# OpenMP producer-consumer using flush

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, openmp

In the consumer branch of the code snippet below, a flush is used to observe any changes to `flag` that might have happened since the previous read, but the `data` variable is not flushed prior to invoking `f()`.

Q1: Should a flush be added to the consumer before invoking `f()`?

Q2: Does the answer change if you assume that `data` is not in the L1 cache of the consumer thread before invoking `f()`?

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel shared(data, flag)
{
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0) {  // Producer.
        // Write to data and make visible to other thread.
        data = computeData();
        #pragma omp flush (data)

        // Write to flag and make visible to other thread.
        flag = 1;
        #pragma omp flush (flag)
    }
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 1) {  // Consumer.
        while (flag == 0) {
            #pragma omp flush (flag)
            ;                         // No-op, flush reloads.
        }
        f(data);                      // Do something with data.
    }  
}
```

Comment: The use of "flush with list" is highly discouraged and leads to fundamentally broken OpenMP programs.  Please consider using the `atomic` construct with added memory-consistency clauses to make sure that you get the desired behavior. it would be best if you would modernize the code by using OpenMP tasks instead, which then directly support the producer/consumer pattern with less hassle and opportunity for error.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKlemm. I am taking a parallel computing class and this code was used as representative example of producer-consumer. I remarked in the class forum that consumer should probably add `flush(data)` or preferably `flush(flag, data)` (in case the compiler reorders `f(data)`).  Overall I agree with you that this code is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the code snippet with the race condition used in my class has been copied from other sources.  I am concurrently reading The OpenMP Common Core [1] and found a race-free equivalent using `atomic` as recommended by @MichaelKlemm.  I modified my original snippet based on Figure 11.5 in [1].

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(data, flag)
{
    int temp = 0;

    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0) {  // Producer.
        // Write to data and make visible to other thread.
        data = computeData();
        #pragma omp flush

        // Write to flag with atomic results in implicit flush.
        #pragma omp atomic write
        flag = 1;
    }   
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 1) {  // Consumer.
        while (!temp) {
            #pragma omp atomic read
            temp = flag;              // Read into temp in case flag changes.
        }   
        #pragma omp flush
        f(data);                      // Do something with data.
    }   
}
```

[1] https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/openmp-common-core